# How to plot $\dot{x}= Ax + Bu$ (x versus t, by matlab)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

I am junior in control.

If $\dot{x} = Ax$ where $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix and $x$ & $\dot{x}$ are $n\times 1$ vectors, by $x = \exp(At)$, we can draw $x$ versus $t$.

---

If $\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$, I want do the same thing, i.e., plot $x$ versus $t$, how should I do
in Matlab?

1. I do not want to integrate it.
2. I know a function called 'lsim', however, it requires $A,B,C,D$. I only have $A$ & $B$.

How should I do?

Comment: Perhaps you can try something like this, but I recommend using symulink for simulation http://www.northeastern.edu/suciu/U345/ode-lab3.pdf, if you want to simulate some specific $x$ then you can write down matrix $C$ to let only this signal to output and set $D$ to zero... C would then be a diagonal matrix size $n\times n$ with only one $1$ on the diagonal, and D would be a zero matrix...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your C=eye(n,n) and D=zeros(n,m), where m is the number of control inputs.  That will give you y=x.  As an example:

n=4;m=1;sys=ss(-eye(n,n)+0.33*rand(n,n),rand(n,m),eye(n,n),zeros(n,m));
u=@(t) sin(t)+cos(2*t);T=linspace(0,10,100);U=u(T);lsim(sys,U,T)